# Run a jar Rhapsody app file

Tags: executable-jar, java, rhapsody

I have created some Java applications to extend Rhapsody using Java API and I have deployed them successfully to the Rhapsody environment (Right click on the project -> Apps).

I can see the exported .jar files under the directory *RhapsodyApps/apps.*

My question is, How can I run them from the command line (Under windows 7)???

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

What I managed to do is to create a .bat file, using "Generate Apps Execution Batch File". As I mentioned in my last post it did not exist in the "Apps" menu of rhapsody.  Besides, it existed in the "...\share\RhapsodyApps\apps" directory with the name "SynchronousScriptInvocation.jar". I hardcoded the RhapsodyApps.hep file, by adding the following:

```
#REM: This app generates a script which will invoke each app synchronously one after another. ...
name7=Apps\Generate Apps Execution Batch File
isPluginCommand7=1
command7=Apps
applicableTo7=Project,SysML,AUTOSAR_40,AUTOSAR_31,AUTOSAR_32,DDS,UPDM1_DoDAF20,UPDM2_DoDAF
isVisible7=1
```

I got the name (Generate Apps Execution Batch File) from the AppInfos.xml file.

Then, the plugin is displayed in the Apps menu in Rhapsody IDE, and I can generate the .bat file. Problems did not stop here. The batch file was not displaying my plugin and the reason was something with my JAVA_PATH configuration. Finally I modified the .bat file as following:

```
@rem This is auto generated script. Be careful on changing it manually.

@rem Build Order
set APP0=0df8829923eb43f4aab9d33ada1ddbf1

@set APPS= %APP0%

set JAVA_PATH=%JAVA_PATH%\bin\java
set JAVA_API=C:/work/User/Build.TRUNK/ProjectName/RhapsodyShare8/JavaAPI
set RhapsodyApps=C:/work/User/Build.TRUNK/ProjectName/RhapsodyShare8/RhapsodyApps

set CLASS_PATH="%RhapsodyApps%"/apps/RhapsodyAppLauncher.jar;"%RhapsodyApps%"/RhapsodyApps.jar;"%RhapsodyApps%"/apps.jar;"%JAVA_API%"/rhapsody.jar

"C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Rational\Rhapsody\8.0.5\jre\bin\java" -cp %CLASS_PATH% -Djava.library.path="%JAVA_API%" apps.RhapsodyLauncherApp %APPS%
```

Finally it works. I hope that this post will help somebody in the future.